# SlickGrid angular2+, making a column clickable

Tags: angular, typescript

I want to make a specific column in slickgrid clickable.i have tried one possible solution but its doesn't seem to work properly.

Here is the code...

```
      routeToDetailsPage(mpn,manufacturer_name){
      this.router.navigate(['/dashboard/part/detail/' + encodeURIComponent(mpn) + '/' 
      + 'itemNumber'], {
      relativeTo: this.activatedRoute,
      queryParams: {
      flag: 'partIqMonitoring',
      manufacture: manufacturer_name,
      mpn: mpn,
      part_type: 'non-electronic'
      }
    });
   }
```

here is the

```
    routeDetails(value,dataContext){
    return '<span 
    (click)=routeToDetailsPage(dataContext.mpn,dataContext.manufacturer_name)></span>'
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question seems incomplete, I'm not sure if you meant cell clicking or column header clicking? Also note that adding Angular code will **not** be interpreted because SlickGrid is a plain JavaScript library and it doesn't know what to do with that code. What will work is probably what is shown below

If you meant cell click and you use [Angular-Slickgrid](https://github.com/ghiscoding/Angular-Slickgrid), then you can use the Angular-Slickgrid `onClick()` or directly on the column definition `onCellClick`, the later is easier since it is defined directly on the column you want (as oppose to the `(click)` which is triggered from any column)

For the cell click defined on the column definition, you can do it this way

```js
this.columnDefinitions = [
  {
    id: 'delete', field: 'id', formatter: Formatters.deleteIcon,

    // on cell click callback
    onCellClick: (e: Event, args: OnEventArgs) => {
      console.log(args);
      if (confirm('Are you sure?')) {
        this.angularGrid.gridService.deleteItemById(args.dataContext.id);
      }
    }
  }
];
```

or from the `(onClick)` triggered by any columns

```html
<angular-slickgrid gridId="grid22"
                       [columnDefinitions]="columnDefinitions"
                       [gridOptions]="gridOptions"
                       [dataset]="dataset"
                       (onAngularGridCreated)="angularGridReady($event.detail)"
                       (onCellChange)="onCellChanged($event.detail.eventData, $event.detail.args)"
                       (onClick)="onCellClicked($event.detail.eventData, $event.detail.args)">
    </angular-slickgrid>
```

then in your Component

```js
onCellClicked(e: Event, args: any) {
  const metadata = this.angularGrid.gridService.getColumnFromEventArguments(args);
  console.log(metadata);

  if (metadata.columnDef.id === 'delete') {
    if (confirm('Are you sure?')) {
      this.angularGrid.gridService.deleteItemById(metadata.dataContext.id);
    }
  }
}
```

Also note that I'm the author of [Angular-Slickgrid](https://github.com/ghiscoding/Angular-Slickgrid) if that is what you are using. If you are not using Angular-Slickgrid, then you should probably take a look at it, since it has all necessary code to work with Angular.